# Google Play Games: different player ids

Tags: google-play-games

I use Games scope to login in my game (`addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)`), and then call `Games.getCurrentPlayerId()`, which returns a string that contains digits only, and when I try to send a gift to this player from another, using `Games.Requests.getSendIntent()`, the `request.getRecipients()` returns an id string which is starting with 'g'. Why are the identifiers different?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [getCurrentPlayer](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Players.html#getCurrentPlayerId(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) reference,
this gets the current signed in player, if available. It is referring to a specific user.

However, [getRecipients](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/request/GameRequest.html#getRecipients())
retrieves the information about all the players that the request was sent to. So this is more than one user. GPGS has its own reasons why it starts with 'g'. You can also do your own naming convention if ever you come up with your own API.

Comment: Why is one (the same) user to have 2 different identifiers for his own device (getCurrentPlayer) and for device of another player (getRecipients)? What is the reason?

Comment: Why does it matter, are they supposed to be the same?

Comment: On my server I use GPGS ID to identify users. For the same user GPGS ID  should be the same, otherwise it is not ID, isn't it?